# Arrange boxplots as a grid with seaborn `FacetGrid`

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, boxplot

I have a data frame with three columns `Features, CV-fold, Accuracy, Network`. I want to have a boxplot for each Network, grouped by the Features and the CV-fold for the axis (see example image).

[image: Output right now]

```
df = pd.read_csv(path)
df['Features'] = df["Features"].astype('category')
ordered_features = sorted(df.Network.value_counts().index)

df = df.loc[df['Accuracy'] > 0.1]
df.Accuracy = df.Accuracy*100

#sns.color_palette("husl", len(df['CV-fold'].value_counts().index))
#sns.set_palette('husl', len(df['CV-fold'].value_counts().index))

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="Network", row_order=ordered_features,
                  height=3, aspect=3, legend_out=True, despine=False)
g.map(sns.boxplot, x="CV-fold", y="Accuracy", hue="Features", data=df, palette='muted').add_legend()

g.set_axis_labels("", "Accuracy (%)")
```

Because I have 8 different networks, I would like to not have them all in a column or a row, but formatted in a grid (e.g. 2x4). Additionally, even though `sharex` is not enabled, the x-axis is only labeled at the very bottom graph.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the `col_wrap` keyword argument to get your plots on multiple rows with multiple columns.

For repeating the x-axis labels use `ax.tick_params()`.

Example:

```
import seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ordered_days = sorted(tips['day'].unique())
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips,col='day',col_order=ordered_days,col_wrap=2)
#                                               change this to 4 ^
g.map(sns.boxplot,'sex','total_bill',palette='muted')
for ax in g.axes.flatten(): 
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Is there a way to increase the margind between the rows of the plots?

Comment: And how can I still specify the order of the networks (days in your case)?

Comment: In your example, it takes the same data for all the sub-plots. I have the same problem. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @Linda: please see edited answer which addresses all three concerns.

Comment: @Linda: it was my mistake, you don't specify data for the map step.

Comment: I also have a hue I need to specify to group the boxplot. Unfortunately, your solution does not work for me. When I call `g.map(sns.boxplot, x="CV-fold", y="Accuracy", hue="Features", palette='muted', width=0.4).add_legend(title='Number of node features:')` I get the error `Could not interpret input 'CV-fold'`. I've tried your exact code and added "smoker" for the hue and it does not work either.

Comment: Ok, I managed now with the hue. But the `plt.tight_layout()` causes the legend to be inside the plot.

Comment: Ok nvm, I managed to fix it by adding the legend after calling tight_layout. Thank you so much for your help!